# Custom Authorization inside REST Service + MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, authorization

We have Implemented REST Based Architecture for our ASP.NET MVC3 App.
We are pondering over the architectural decision to implement a custom Authorization for the contracts we are exposing through our service.

e.g. Any valid authenticated user may get access to a particular Method implementation of the contract and might want to access some other user's info (getting a list of items from the data through Stored Proc) , we need to check after we get back this Items list that whether this authenticated User has proper permissions to access this. The permission check is based on a heavy business  logic , hence Attribute based authorization might not be helpful in this scenario as only after getting back the data we might decide the access permission check.

Please advice how to implement this security model inside our REST Service.

Answer (score 1):

Since attribute based auth seemingly won't work for you, then you'll need to determine if they fit the role you need:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole()
```

After that your controller simply returns an

```
HttpUnauthorizedResult
```

which is an ActionResult.
So check your business logic, if they aren't authorized, then return HttpUnauthorizedResult and you are done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult.httpunauthorizedresult(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Adam thanks.I think I was not clear in mentioning the issue.I will try to explain it through an example:Let's say you have a View called ProductsView , its Model: ProductsModel , its Controller: ProductsController , REST Based service to get List of Products: IProducts (implementaion iside Products class with GetProducts method) . Now inside the Controller calls the Model's method to retrieve a list of Products,the Model in turn calls the REST Service:https://blah/GetProducts/?userName='xyz'. Now the  user:xyz is a valid user validated through the MVC Security model we have in place

Comment: Once the Call goes to the REST Service: GetProducts/?username='xyz' the service will get a list of products from the database ; after getting back this list we need to  check whether certain Items inside this list are allowed access to a user based on a complex business logic.Hence after getting back the data we need to perform this authorization check. So we are thinking how to implement this scenario inside our Service Code, where you do the authorization once the data is retrieved.

Comment: just an fyi, models generally should be lightweight and not have any behavior unless related to a view. A repository would do this and then return a model or models. With the security q though, what happens when the user isn't authorized. Do you want an HTTP401 code returned, or just the products removed?

Comment: Adam...the Model is lightweight dealing only with View related stuff...the authorization happens through an attribute on the controller action. If the user is not authorized to access a particular item in the list , the service just ignores that item and returns all the items that he has access to...!

Comment: Then you need to pass the applicable users roles to your service (can be on the uri path if its a single role or on the querystring for multiple)  if its in its own environment, or your service needs access to the same datastore where your roles are kept for a user so it can query them.

Comment: thanks for your prompt responses Adam...we will analyze this approach for our scenario...